# How to combine these two LINQ statements into one query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I am a new user of LINQ and I am trying right now to retrieve the number of posted answers on the last quiz and the total score of that last quiz. The difficulty is that I have the following two tables which I need to write one LINQ statement to retrieve what it is required.

***Part of the database schema:***

```
Quiz Table: ID, Description, TotalScore
QuizAnswers Table: ID, Score, QuizID
```

I could be able to retrieve the required information by writing two LINQ statements, but actually I need to write one statement or combine both of them into one query so I can bind a GridView control to it

***To retrieve the number of posted answers on the last quiz:***

```
var lastQuizId = context.Tbl_QuizAnswers.Max(s => s.ID);
var numOfAnswers = context.Tbl_QuizAnswers.Where(s => s.QuizID == lastQuizId).Count();
return numOfAnswers;
```

***To retrieve the total score of that last quiz:***

```
var lastQuizId = context.Tbl_Quiz.Max(s => s.ID);
var totalScore = context.Tbl_Quiz.Where(s => s.ID == lastQuizId).Select(s => s.TotalScore).First();
return totalScore;
```

**So could you please help me by telling me how to combine those two queries?**

Answer (score 0):

```
(from q in context.Tbl_Quiz
select new {
             Quiz = q, 
             Answers = q.Tbl_QuizAnswers, 
             AnswerCount = q.Tbl_QuizAnswers.Count, 
             Max = q.Max(q.TotalScore)
           }
orderby q.ID desc)
.FirstOrDefault()
```

If you don't have relationships setup properly you can use those queries you have for `Answers` and `AnswerCount`, but by using `q`